# Pyramid open source web application

Tags: python, pyramid

I want to start learning Pyramid and I searched a lot to find a web application written using Pyramid that is open source and preferably available on the web... I would like a website similar to https://www.pythonanywhere.com/
It would be great if the application would have authentication, registration and access control lists implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are learning I would recommend you the Pyramid Wiki Tutorial which includes authentication and ACL examples. If you want the work with pyramid application in production, check out the following project. They also have a live website which is great if you want to check it out first.

[Source Code](https://github.com/Pylons/substanced)

[Demo Website](http://substanced.net/)

Answer (score 1):

We recently launched a website that serves as an entry point for developers who want to [try Pyramid](http://trypyramid.com/).  From there you can Learn how to write stuff with Pyramid using the Tutorials, the Quick Tour, and the Cookbook.